# The user process is waiting for "Building a workspace" to complete in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a problem in eclipse whenever i run my jsp project window pops up

[image: this]

and i am unable to run the project.I tried to restart eclipse and also tried some solutions from stack but it dint help.Due to this i cant do anything in eclipse.

How to remove this Building workspace from progress bar?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Project -> Build Automatically off. Also, Try to disable some of validation in Preference menu including JSP, JS, etc if you don't care about them.